# code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Key may not be empty"

Tags: python, cassandra

I'm trying to insert a Python dictionary and I got the `code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Key may not be empty"` error when I was writing to cassandra DB. Do anyone have an idea what's going on?

Casandra writer:

```
def writer(**kwargs):
    try:
        openEventStream.create(
            venue_name = get_dict_val(kwargs, 'venue_name'),
            venue_lon = get_dict_val(kwargs, 'venue_lon'),
            ....
        )
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Actually write into cassandra:

```
def fetch_data(messages):
    for message in messages:
        # venue
        venue = get_dict_val(message, 'venue')
        if venue:
            venue_name = get_dict_val(venue, 'venue_name')
            venue_lon = get_dict_val(venue, 'venue_lon')
            ...
        else:
            venue_name, venue_lon = None, None                

        writer(venue_name = venue_name, venue_lon = venue_lon)
```

then execute:

```
fetch_data(some_nested_dict)
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Seems like you are trying to insert null into a column that shouldn't be null

Comment: Thanks Gergely! I added some code

Comment: Hi TheGeorgeous, thanks :) I see. But what would cause it to happen? For example, I only have primary key and don't have any other requirements for columns.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like either you are not inserting data in your all the partition key or in all the clustering column.